# PHP variable is not shown as an integer

Tags: php

```
if($koltukk%4 == 2){
    if($koltukk > 1000){
    $koltukH = "B";
    (int)$koltukR = ($koltukk / 4) + 1;//Doesnt work (int)
            }
    else{
    $koltukH = "E";
    (int)$koltukR = ($koltukk / 4) + 1;//Doesnt work (int)

        }


    }

$koltukR = ($koltukk / 4) + 1;
```

I want to get the $koltukR variable as an integer but i couldn't do it (int) did not work

Comment: Get rid of the `(int)`'s. They aren't valid in PHP the way you are using them.

Comment: Try `$koltukR = (int)(($koltukk / 4) + 1);`

Comment: I am curious, @John Conde, why do you put your answer in the comments instead of writing an answer? I have seen that before but I don't understand...

Comment: @DamienPirsy he is not, you are getting confused with the variable names. It is `$koltukH` and `$koltukk`

Comment: @FabienWarniez Because John is posting a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @DigitalChris Very confusing indeed.

Comment: these variable names are turkish which is my mean language so they may mean absurd to you@DigitalChris

Comment: One important note here: intval() is NOT round(). intval() is similar to floor().

I think what you really want is round(): see my answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter the language; if someone tried to use alphabetk, alphabetH, alphabetR, I would say the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `(int)` casting on the other side of the assignment operator:

```
$koltukR = (int)(($koltukk / 4) + 1);
```

Or, use `intval()` like this:

```
$kolturR = intval(($koltukk / 4) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$koltukR = intval(($koltukk / 4) + 1);
```

You should use better variable names, move the math out of the if/else since both are the same, and you shouldn't even need to cast this as an int manually.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an `intval()` method that turns a variable into an integer. Pass in your variable as a parameter.

[intval()](https://www.php.net/intval)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if($koltukk%4 == 2)
{
    if($koltukk > 1000)
    {
        $koltukH = "B";
        $koltukR = (int)(($koltukk / 4) + 1);
    } else{
        $koltukH = "E";
        $koltukR = (int)(($koltukk / 4) + 1);    
    }
}

echo $koltukR;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One important note here: intval() is NOT round(). intval() is similar to floor().

I think what you really want is round():

Here's the real answer: K.I.S.S.

```
if($k%4 == 2){
    if($k > 1000){
        $H = "B"    
    }
    else{
        $H = "E";
    }    
}
$R = round($k / 4) + 1;
```

Stealing an example from https://www.php.net/intval to illustrate:

```
echo number_format(8.20*100, 20), "<br />";
echo intval(8.20*100), "<br />";
echo floor(8.20*100), "<br />";
echo round(8.20*100), "<br />";

819.99999999999988631316
819
819
820
```

Comment: Good to point out that this can definitely be refactored, though not actually answering the original question about integer type casting.